# What's the most efficient way to refresh a tableView every time the app is pushed back to the foreground?

Tags: ios, swift, completionhandler

Currently what I have is this:

AppDelegate.applicationDidBecomeActive():

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    guard let vc = self.window?.rootViewController?.children.first as! AlarmTableViewController? else {
        fatalError("Could not downcast rootViewController to type AlarmTableViewController, exiting")
    }
    vc.deleteOldAlarms(completionHandler: { () -> Void in
        vc.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

deleteOldAlarms():

```
func deleteOldAlarms(completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    os_log("deleteOldAlarms() called", log: OSLog.default, type: .default)
    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    var activeNotificationUuids = [String]()
    var alarmsToDelete = [AlarmMO]()
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    notificationCenter.getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { (requests) in
        for request in requests {
            activeNotificationUuids.append(request.identifier)
        }
        for alarm in self.alarms {
            guard let alarmUuids = alarm.value(forKey: "notificationUuids") as! [String]? else {
                os_log("Found nil when attempting to unwrap notificationUuids in deleteOldAlarms() in AlarmTableViewController.swift, cancelling",
                       log: OSLog.default, type: .default)
                return
            }
            let activeNotificationUuidsSet: Set<String> = Set(activeNotificationUuids)
            let alarmUuidsSet: Set<String> = Set(alarmUuids)
            let union = activeNotificationUuidsSet.intersection(alarmUuidsSet)
            if union.isEmpty {
                alarmsToDelete.append(alarm)
            }
        }
        os_log("Deleting %d alarms", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug, alarmsToDelete.count)
        for alarmMOToDelete in alarmsToDelete {
            self.removeNotifications(notificationUuids: alarmMOToDelete.notificationUuids as [String])
            managedContext.delete(alarmMOToDelete)
            self.alarms.removeAll { (alarmMO) -> Bool in
                return alarmMOToDelete == alarmMO
            }
        }
        completionHandler()
    })

}
```

but it feels disgusting. Plus, I'm calling tableView.reloadData() on a background thread now (the thread executing the completion handler). What's the best way to refresh the UI once the user opens the app back up? What I'm aiming for is for these old alarms to be deleted and for the view to be reloaded. An alarm is considered old if it doesn't have any notifications pending in the notification center (meaning the notification has already been executed).

Comment: You could use a notification with NSNotificationCenter?

Comment: Use a notification to do what, update the view? I assume you're saying to use the notification to trigger something to happen in the app, right? How do I do that? Plus, wouldn't that action only get triggered if the user taps on the notification?

Comment: What is your question about? The implementation of `deleteOldAlarms` or the need to call it from the app delegate?

Comment: view controller has nothing to do with deleteOldAlarms as i see. so better to manage alarms with alarmmanager class maybe and resfresh tableView in viewdidload.

Comment: I'm more asking about what pattern I should use to refresh the view, given that I need to call notificationCenter.getPendingNotificationRequests() in deleteOldAlarms(), and I need to call deleteOldAlarms() every time the app comes into the foreground. If I call deleteOldAlarms(), do I keep the completionHandler pattern for refreshing the view, since the view doesn't need to be refreshed until that getPendingNotificationRequests() method is done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put any code in the app delegate. Have the view controller register to receive notifications when the app enters the foreground.

Add this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(enteringForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
```

Then add:

```
@objc func enteringForeground() {
    deleteOldAlarms {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

As of iOS 13, you should register for `UIScene.willEnterForegroundNotification`. If your app needs to work under iOS 13 as well as iOS 12 then you need to register for both notifications but you can use the same selector.

Comment: What does `DispatchQueue.main.asyc` do, and why should I use it?

Comment: It ensures that `reloadData` is called on the main queue.

Comment: So do you think I should use the completionHandler pattern in deleteOldAlarms(), or is there some other better way to refresh the view once the getPendingNotificationRequests() method is done?

Comment: Definitely keep the completion handler. That makes `deleteOldAlarms` a bit more generic. All it does is delete the old alarms and update the data model. Let the completion handler decide what to do when that's done (such as reload the table view).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSNotification`

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didBecomeActive), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

In `didBecomeActive` call `tableView.reloadData()`, that should be all. You should remember to unregister the observer in `deinit`.

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```